# Multiexponential analysis of infection counts with errors

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, applied-mathematics

In the past, I have seen some decompositions of sums of exponential decays into components by the [Padé-Laplace method](https://www.nature.com/articles/326169a0): Apply the Laplace transform $${\frak L}(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e^{k_i t}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{s-k_i} $$

and then use [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) to find the best rational approximations $p(s)/q(s)$ of degrees $n-1$ over $n$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ and partial fraction decomposition to find the poles and coefficients. This often lets one determine what $n$ is and does not seem overly sensitive to noise.

**Is this suitable and an efficient use of sparse data when analyzing sums of increasing exponentials? If not, what is a better approach?** The model that I have in mind is an epidemic spreading at different rates through a small number of different communities with noisy aggregate (country-level) death counts. There has been some discussion of affecting $R_0 = \max k_i$, but with different responses and [compliance rates](https://www.google.com/covid19/mobility/) in different areas, I don't think a single exponential is appropriate.